# Write files to directory in sorted order

Tags: java, io, sorting

This program simply sorts a folder of images files by size and outputs them to a new directory. However whenever I view the directory it is not maintained in the sorted order. Any solutions would be beneficial.

Here are the relevant code snippets

```
class CompareFileSize implements Comparator<File>{
    public int compare(File s1, File s2) {
        long len1 = s1.length();
        long len2 = s2.length();

        if (len1 > len2){
            return 1;
        }else if (len1 < len2){
            return -1;
        }else
            return 0;
    }
}
public class FileSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File p = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\newFolder");
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\oldFolder");
        File myPics [] = f.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> aList = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myPics.length; i++){
            aList.add(myPics[i]);

        }
        System.out.println("Before----------------------------------------");
        for (File uimage: aList){
            System.out.println(uimage);
        }

        System.out.println("After-----------------------------------------");

        Collections.sort(aList, new CompareFileSize());

        for (File image: aList){
            System.out.println(image);
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(image, p);
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you "*view the directory*"?

Answer (score 3):

> However whenever I view the directory it is not maintained in the sorted order. Any solutions would be beneficial.

Why there may be an inherent order to how files are stored in a directory, your directory viewer will always override this with the current preference (sort by filesize, sort by modified date, sort by name alphabetically).

Your code won't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you couldn't store them in the order specified by the code.